# Content Based on Date

Tags: php

I would like to display the content on the 9th, 20th and 25th of each month

This do not work this way ...Where am i Wrong ?

```
<?php if( date( 'd' ) == array(5,9,20,25) ):?>
15th and 20th and 25th content

<?php else: ?>
Other days of content

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Try to use `'j'` instead of `'d'`. Because "`'d'` could have leading zero.

Comment: Use [in_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if an array contains a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code compares a string `date('d')` with an `array()`, which will never hit. You need [`in_array()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for this task:

```
// if date('d') exists in array [5,9,20,25]
<?php if( in_array(date( 'd' ), array(5,9,20,25)) ):?>
     15th and 20th and 25th content
<?php else: ?>
     Other days of content
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check a value against multiple values, then you can use in_array() function which takes the first parameter as the niddle and another array as a haystack. Learn more about his from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
 <?php if( in_array(date( 'd' ), array(5,9,20,25)) ):?>
    15th and 20th and 25th content
<?php else: ?>
    Other days of content
<?php endif;?>
```